# Not Enough Arguments For an IF Statement...But There Are

Tags: excel

When I run this equation in Excel it tells me that there is only 1 argument for the IF statement. I am not sure why it is saying that when I have 3 arguments. Within the OR statement I have 2 different AND statements. It works just fine if I get rid of the second AND statement. Did I mess up a parentheses somewhere? I am not sure what is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
=IF(OR(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(B19:O19,{"I","Ip","Ia","It","Ih","A","Aa","Ap","At","Ah","X","R","Rt","Rx","Rp","Rh","K","Kt","E","Et","AL","HL","TV*","FFSL","ADM*"})))=10, AND(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(B19:O19,{"R-10","Rx-10*","Rp-10","Rt-10*","Rh-10","I-10","Ia-10","Ip-10","It-10","Ih-10","X-10*","A-10*","At-10"})))=4, ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(B19:O19,{"I","Ip","Ia","It","Ih","A","Aa","Ap","At","Ah","X","R","Rt","Rx","Rp","Rh","K","Kt","E","Et","AL","HL","TV*","FFSL","ADM*"})))=5),AND(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(B19:O19,{"HL-9","X-9","N-9","E-9","J-9","Jh-9","Nh-9","Eh-9"})))=8,ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(B19:O19,{"I","Ip","Ia","It","Ih","A","Aa","Ap","At","Ah","X","R","Rt","Rx","Rp","Rh","K","Kt","E","Et","AL","HL","TV*","FFSL","ADM*"})))=1) ,"80 Hours","Error"))
```

Comment: yes, you messed up a parenthesis somewhere (there are two closing parentheses at the end, so `"80 Hours"` and `"Error"` are *inside* the `OR` statement - I'm guessing you wanted them outside).

Comment: Ah, yes, I am pretty sure I want them in the IF statement. I'll see if I can find it... Thanks.

Comment: Yep. That was it. Thanks! Just moved that last ")" before the "80 Hours".

Answer (score 2):

This question makes me think "If only there was an online Excel Formula Beautifier".

Oh look, [there is](http://excelformulabeautifier.com/).

If you copy-and-paste it into the beautifier you get the code below.
You can now see that your parameters "80 Hours", "Error" are parameters of the first ARRAYFORMULA function, not the IF function.

```
=IF(
    OR(
        ARRAYFORMULA(
            SUM(
                COUNTIF(
                    B19:O19,
{ "I",
                            "Ip",
                            "Ia",
                            "It",
                            "Ih",
                            "A",
                            "Aa",
                            "Ap",
                            "At",
                            "Ah",
                            "X",
                            "R",
                            "Rt",
                            "Rx",
                            "Rp",
                            "Rh",
                            "K",
                            "Kt",
                            "E",
                            "Et",
                            "AL",
                            "HL",
                            "TV*",
                            "FFSL",
                            "ADM*"
                        ARRAYROWSTOP)
                    ARRAYSTOP)
                )
            )
        ) = 10,
        AND(
            ARRAYFORMULA(
                SUM(
                    COUNTIF(
                        B19:O19,
{ "R-10",
                                "Rx-10*",
                                "Rp-10",
                                "Rt-10*",
                                "Rh-10",
                                "I-10",
                                "Ia-10",
                                "Ip-10",
                                "It-10",
                                "Ih-10",
                                "X-10*",
                                "A-10*",
                                "At-10"
                            ARRAYROWSTOP)
                        ARRAYSTOP)
                    )
                )
            ) = 4,
            ARRAYFORMULA(
                SUM(
                    COUNTIF(
                        B19:O19,
{ "I",
                                "Ip",
                                "Ia",
                                "It",
                                "Ih",
                                "A",
                                "Aa",
                                "Ap",
                                "At",
                                "Ah",
                                "X",
                                "R",
                                "Rt",
                                "Rx",
                                "Rp",
                                "Rh",
                                "K",
                                "Kt",
                                "E",
                                "Et",
                                "AL",
                                "HL",
                                "TV*",
                                "FFSL",
                                "ADM*"
                            ARRAYROWSTOP)
                        ARRAYSTOP)
                    )
                )
            ) = 5
        ),
        AND(
            ARRAYFORMULA(
                SUM(
                    COUNTIF(
                        B19:O19,
{ "HL-9",
                                "X-9",
                                "N-9",
                                "E-9",
                                "J-9",
                                "Jh-9",
                                "Nh-9",
                                "Eh-9"
                            ARRAYROWSTOP)
                        ARRAYSTOP)
                    )
                )
            ) = 8,
            ARRAYFORMULA(
                SUM(
                    COUNTIF(
                        B19:O19,
{ "I",
                                "Ip",
                                "Ia",
                                "It",
                                "Ih",
                                "A",
                                "Aa",
                                "Ap",
                                "At",
                                "Ah",
                                "X",
                                "R",
                                "Rt",
                                "Rx",
                                "Rp",
                                "Rh",
                                "K",
                                "Kt",
                                "E",
                                "Et",
                                "AL",
                                "HL",
                                "TV*",
                                "FFSL",
                                "ADM*"
                            ARRAYROWSTOP)
                        ARRAYSTOP)
                    )
                )
            ) = 1
        ),
        "80 Hours",
        "Error"
    )
)
```

Comment: Or to make it even more beautiful, replace it with not-Excel.

Comment: That's good to know. Sorry for the bad original posting. Thanks for your help!